# Unable to find Android SDK(command line tools) in VS code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, android-sdk-tools

I am new to flutter world,
I have installed command line tools and running flutter doctor command in vs code.
But its showing

> Unable to find android tool chain

[image]

This is the path to my command line tools of android SDK

[image]

I have also added path in my environment variable

[image]

I tried to configure this path multiple times.

This is how I tried to set path for my android sdk tools multiple times

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK is composed of multiple packages that are required for app development. This page lists the most important command line tools that are available, organized by the packages in which they're delivered.

You can install and update each package using Android Studio's SDK Manager or the sdkmanager command line tool. All of the packages are downloaded into your Android SDK directory, which you can locate as follows:

In Android Studio, click File > Project Structure.
Select SDK Location in the left pane. The path is shown under Android SDK location.
Android SDK Command-Line Tools
Located in: android_sdk/cmdline-tools/version/bin/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved the problem by creating an empty folder and named it "platforms" at the Android SDK root folder.